# Limit output in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, limit, strpos

I want to check in an xml file with CDATA if cities exist.
If the cities exist one or more time, then I want to display an input.

I have found several ways to check if the city exists or not, however as it exists several times it display several times.

Both ways below prints out correctly, but I need only one output:

```
foreach($paradasarray as $parada){
    if (substr_count($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') > 0) {
        echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
    }
    if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') !== false) {
        echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
    }   
}

Both ways outputs like this:
Benalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena 
CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena 
CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena 
CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena 
CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena CostaBenalmádena
```

Comment: use `break;` in your if statements

Comment: how easy lol, I only tried that in the foreach. That works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways of doing this.

1. You could use [breaks](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

```
foreach($paradasarray as $parada){
    if (substr_count($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') > 0) {
        echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
        break;
    }
    if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') !== false) {
        echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
        break;
    }   
}
```

2. You could set a boolean value before the foreach and change it when benalmadena costa is printed.

This comes in handy when you dont want the foreach to end.

```
$benalmadena=false;
foreach($paradasarray as $parada){
    if($benalmadena==false){
       if (substr_count($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') > 0) {
            echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
            $benalmadena=true;
        }

        if (strpos($parada->localidad, 'Benalmádena') !== false) {
            echo 'Benalmádena Costa';
            $benalmadena=true;
        }
    }else{
        //Other code you want to happen even after Benalmadena is printed  
    }
}
```